# Java Profiling of Unit Tests

Tags: java, maven, junit, profiling, junit-jupiter

I created some Integration Tests for the Top 5 endpoints of my Spring Boot app, and run them in a test Suite.

Is there a way to get a Report like the one you get in NewRelic but as artifact after the maven run? Kind of like Jacoco but with the info that NewRelic gives (Method profiling, class profiling, Telemetry, ...).
Edit: My options right now are: Do an agent with Bytebuddy or Deploy some performace tool, no free options. As this is not a weird ask I though there might be a mvn plugin already, but have not find it.